# Threads not synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to multithreading and read about synchrohnization of threads.

For practice i wrote the below class and have a synchronized block with 2 threads running but it doesn't work .Please help me where i am going wrong. Here is the code snippet.

```
public class Thread7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Ter first = new Ter();
        Ter second= new Ter();
        first.start();
        second.start();
    }

}

class Ter extends Thread
{

private Object aa = new Object();

public void run() {
    synchronized (aa) {
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                System.out.println(i + Thread.currentThread().getName() + Thread.holdsLock(aa));
                Thread.sleep(2000);

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. As such it is painful to read. Thanks.

Comment: Unless you lock on a shared resource/Object it doesn't do anything. Pass the object for locking to each thread.

Comment: Each thread has its own lock object, they aren't sharing. There's a duplicate here somewhere...

Comment: Thanks for the help .. got the point.. :)

Comment: The object/lock "aa" was different for both the threads and was not shared